# Histogram Matching

Tags: opencv, histogram

I am using calcBackProject to find an object in a frame and it works somehow well scanning all the frame. but I need to enhance it

In my code at some point I have a motion detection mask and based on it I generated contours for candidate objects (objects that move and might be the target)

could I utilise this to calculate histogram for each contour and match it to the histogram of the target?

- how to calculate histogram for each contour?
  calcHist accepts mask but how to pass the contour as a mask
  -how to match?

Comment: Draw a filled contour using drawContours and pass it as the mask.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your contour to a mask and use the mask in calcHist.
In C++ it would be done like this :

```
/**
 * Converts a contour to a binary mask.
 * The parameter mask should be a matrix of type CV_8UC1 with proper
 * size to hold the mask.
 * @param contour The contour to convert.
 * @param mask The Mat where the mask will be written. Must have proper size
 * and type before callign convertContourToMask.
 */
void convertContourToMask( const std::vector<cv::Point>& contour, cv::Mat& mask )
{
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contoursVector;
    contoursVector.push_back( contour );
    cv::Scalar white = cv::Scalar(255);
    cv::Scalar black = cv::Scalar(0);
    mask.setTo(black);
    cv::drawContours(mask, contoursVector, -1, white, CV_FILLED);
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: you can use: `drawContours(image, vector<vector<Point>> {contour}, -1, Scalar(0, 255, 0), CV_FILLED);`. You don't need an empty `hierarchy`, `CV_FILLED` is clearer than `-1`. You don't need to set other parameters to default values.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer with your suggested improvement. I'll keep the temporal variables though since I think that putting too much into the parameters makes reading it more difficult. But it is just a matter of preference.